# Anyone has Spotify Streaming SDK sources for Android?

Tags: android, spotify

Anyone has Spotify Streaming SDK sources for Android, because Spotify deleted repo? Or can you help me where I can find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the following announcement: https://developer.spotify.com/community/news/2019/09/09/streaming-repo-shutdown-date/

**Summary:** They shutdown the Streaming SDK as it wasn't maintained and they want to urge developers to use the latest SDKs:

- Auth SDK
- App Remote SDK

More info at:  https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/